# Is there a way to use LaTeX in forums that aren't equipped with it?

Tags: mathjax

I'm writing some math-related stuff for a particular forum, and could really use LaTeX formatting—but the forum itself isn't equipped with LaTeX.

Is there an easy way I can use it anyway? Say, for example, some online editor where I can literally copy/paste LaTeX-formatted pictures into said forum post?

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic here, but I'm also not exactly sure what you're after. Online editor... there are plenty, but they require complete documents rather than code snippets. There are editors that handle code snippets for math processing (mainly), but I don't know whether they all export to images. Surely you can create your own output locally, and then copy-and-paste the images, but that seems trivial in terms of a solution... only if you have a local distribution of TeX.

Comment: You could write LaTeX math mode snippets in the [Wikipedia sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Sandbox) and copy the generated images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can link to images in the *particular forum*, you can use the [CodeCogs LaTeX equation editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), which produces an image, that can also be directly linked.

The image is even produced with a nice URL like `https://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?\sum^{i%3D\infty}_{i%3D0}x_{i}}` and produces an image which can be directly embedded (with proper URL encoding for brackets, etc.), as shown below.

[image]

To help with the correct URL encoding, you can use [many available tools](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=online+url+encode).

Answer (score 0):

If the forum have rich text editing and allows images you can use [Markdown Here](http://markdown-here.com/). A chrome extension that allows you to write in Markdown and then convert it.